# Three js perspective/trackerball controls maxDistance minDistance not working when using OrthographicCamera

Tags: three.js

I am working on a 3js project which needs to use OrthographicCamera and perspective or trackerball controls. When I use perspectiveCamera everything works well and I can limite zoom in or zoom out distances by setting minDistance and maxDistance properties of the controls, however, once I switched to OrthographicCamera, this function stopped working. I tried to manually manipulate the mouse wheel events by changing the camera position z as well, but the results is the same, it works on the perspectiveCamera but not OrthographicCamera.

```
    <script type="module">
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const width =200;
            const height = 200;
            const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( width / - 2, width / 2, height / 2, height / - 2, 1, 1000 );
            /* const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, width / height, 1, 1000 ); */

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            import { OrbitControls  } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
            const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.minDistance = 70;
            controls.maxDistance= 100;

            const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30,30,30);
            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: "grey", } );
            const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( cube );

            camera.position.z = 70;

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
            animate();
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation page](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls) of `THREE.OrbitControls`, the properties `minDistance` and `maxDistance` only work with perspective cameras. The reason for this is that zooming with perspective cameras is implemented via dollying (so the camera is translated along its viewing direction).

That is not true for orthographic cameras. In this context `THREE.OrbitControls` implements zooming with a modification of the camera's projection matrix. You have to controls the minimum and maximum zoom with the properties `minZoom` and `maxZoom`.